# como crear un GET y POST en la misma ruta con Django

Tags: python, django

Quiero mostrar una lista de libros, y en la misma página también tener un formulario para agregar libros, **pero solo se puede mostrar uno**(o se muestra la lista o se muestra el formulario), quería consultarles ¿Cómo puedo hacer las dos cosas en la misma ruta?**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('books', views.BooksList.as_view(), name='books'),
path('books', views.addBook, name ="addBooks"), 
]
```

views.py

```
class BooksList(ListView): 
    model = booksTable 
    template_name = 'booksLoans/books.html'
    paginate_by = 10

def addBook(request):
    form = PostBooks()
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = PostBooks(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            instancia = form.save(commit=False)
            instancia.save()   
            return redirect('books')
    return render(request, 'booksLoans/books.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def buscarEventosPorIdioma(request):
    formulario = IdiomaBusquedaForm()
    eventos = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = IdiomaBusquedaForm(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            eventos = Evento.objects.all().filter(lenguajes__contains=formulario.cleaned_data['idioma'])

    return render(request, 'busqueda_idiomas.html', {'formulario': formulario, 'eventos': eventos, 'STATIC_URL': settings.STATIC_URL})
```

Aquí puedes ver que le paso al método como parámetros request y le pregunto si es POST o no.